# How to insert the tcm id of the page into the page source in Tridion

Tags: 2011, dwt

How do I go about retrieving the page's tcm id and insert it as a comment in the page source using a Dreamweaver Template?

Comment: Please eddit your question with some more information like what you have tried, what you are using... Most of us arent mindreaders ;-)

Comment: @Chris: are you sure your edit is valid? The OP didn't specify DWT.

Comment: @Puf - no not sure - but the post was flagged for deletion - So I figured I would make it relevant to the only answer so that it at least makes sense. If the OP wants to update it to be more specific, then they can do so.  Would you have rather deleted the Q & A?

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way is to modify the Tridion Page Template(s) to include something like this in your Dreamweaver Template Building Block:

```
<!-- PageId: @@Page.Id@@ -->
```

At publish time Tridion will resolve Page.Id to the current page's ID and output something along these lines:

```
<!-- PageId: tcm:123-123-64 -->
```

If you're not using Dreamweaver templating, or you don't want to use Tridion templates for this, then please expand on your question.

Comment: This solution should work.